# What is "Scala Presentation Compiler"?

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

What is the "Scala Presentation Compiler"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Scala Presentation Compiler is provided as part of Scala so that IDEs can have access to the intermediate information that doesn't make it into the final compiled output.

A quick googling gives [this](http://ensime.blogspot.com/2010/08/building-ide-with-scala-presentation.html).  Odersky also discussed it in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqQNqIy5LdM&t=22m0s) (very interesting) talk about what's coming in Scala 2.10 (at about 22 minutes in).

Comment: It would be better if you've linked that youtube video exactly at the time when Martin talks about Presentation Compiler (so others wouldn't need to search through the video).

Comment: As a side note, I believe IDEA doesn't use it, but instead implemented their own version.

Comment: On the IDEA topic, you are right. Here is the November 2011 thread where the question is asked: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/430505 Alexander's reply is "I'm not sure that we will do it. We will spend time on improving current plugin, and I hope It will not be behind."

Answer (score 7):

It's a compiler that provides the hooks necessary to work well to support the interactive features of an IDE, like color-coding, autocompletion, etc.  One of the technical challenges is efficiently staying in sync with what's been edited.  See [this talk.](https://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/Scaladays_2011_resources.html#ScalaDays2011Resources-TheScalaIDEforEclipsereloaded)